# SharePoint C# Get list of sites and subsites on which user has permission (like Read, Contribute Visitor)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

```
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
            foreach (SPWeb oWeb in oSite.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
            {
                permission = string.Empty;
                foreach (SPGroup group in oWeb.Groups)
                {
                    foreach (SPUser u in group.Users)
                    {
                        if (u.Name == (userName))
                        {
                            foreach (SPRole role in u.Roles)
                            {
                                permission += role.Name.ToString() + ", ";
                            }
                                                       }
                    } // Taking All Permission details of user
                }
                permission = " [" + permission.TrimEnd(", ".ToCharArray()) + "]";
            }
        }
```

my final string variable will have values like `[Read, Visitor]` or `[Read]` or `[visitor, Read]`

I wants to have all permission names and Actually I am getting error/warning on u.Roles [Roles is absolute now],

Help me to get permission by using `SPRoleDefination` etc 
`SPRoleDefinitionCollectionroleDefinitions = oWeb.RoleDefinitions;`
`SPRoleDefinitionroleDefinition`

Thanks
Praveen

Comment: Specify the error/warning message please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 foreach (SPWeb oWeb in oSite.RootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
            {

                SPRoleDefinitionCollection oCollection= oWeb.RoleDefinitions;

                foreach (SPRoleDefinition r in oCollection)
                {
                    SPRoleDefinition roleDef = oCollection[r.Name.ToString()];

                    foreach (SPRoleAssignment oAssigment in oWeb.RoleAssignments)
                    {
                        if (oAssigment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Contains(roleDef))
                        {
                            permissions+= r.Name.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Thanks,I have resolved can refer below blog : 
http://praveenpandit.blogspot.in/2013/08/sharepoint-get-all-permission-and-list.html